# Seeing if multiple dates fall within date ranges in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following sample data:

```
A      B                C        D  E   F      G
Ref1   01/01/2018   31/12/2018          Ref1   01/04/2019   
Ref3   01/03/2018   28/02/2019          Ref2   14/01/2018   
Ref2   01/01/2017   31/12/2017                  
Ref1   01/01/2019   31/12/2019
```

I'd like to know if it is possible, via formula or VBA, to check if the Refs and Dates in columns F & G fall within the data found in columns A, B & C.

So the Expected output would be:

```
A      B                C        D  E   F      G           H
Ref1   01/01/2018   31/12/2018          Ref1   01/04/2019  Found    
Ref3   01/03/2018   28/02/2019          Ref2   14/01/2018  Not Found    
Ref2   01/01/2017   31/12/2017                  
Ref1   01/01/2019   31/12/2019
```

I know how to use a `vlookup` to see the Refs exist in column A, but not how to compare the dates.

Comment: you are trying to found Date in G column is fall in between column B and Column C... am I right

Comment: @DineshVilasPawar Yes, where the Ref matches also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

COUNTIFS will do what you need.

The following formula in Cell H2 will count the matches found:

```
=COUNTIFS(A$2:A$5,F2,B$2:B$5,"<="&G2,C$2:C$5,">="&G2)
```

You can copy this down as needed (Note the $ prefix on the row numbers for the ranges A-C, which keeps the 3 search ranges fixed when you copy the formula down) .

You can convert to Found / Not found if you wish:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A$2:A$5,F2,B$2:B$5,"<="&G2,C$2:C$5,">="&G2),"Found","Not found")
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
=FILTER(A86:C89, COUNTIFS(E86:E89, A86:A89,
                          F86:F89, ">="&B86:B89,
                          F86:F89, "<="&C86:C89))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Is that Google Sheets? `FILTER()` is a beta function in Excel and isn't available to most users (I get "This function isn't valid").